# Remove subsequent duplicate elements by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

Via javascript or jquery, I am in need of removing duplicate elements in sets so that one remains. They're all the same, so it doesn't matter which are removed so long as one remains. The page appears as follows:

```
<div class="column-hr"></div>
<div class="column-hr"></div>
<div class="column-dude"></div>
<div class="column-hr"></div>
<div class="column-hr"></div>
<div class="column-dude"></div>
<div class="column-hr"></div>
```

One `<div class="column-hr"></div>` before every `<div class="column-dude"></div>` needs to stay, but every subsequent hr column before every dude column needs to go.

I tried the following, hoping it would be this simple. Didn't work.

```
$( "div.column-hr" ).each(function( index ) {
    if ($(this).next('div.column.hr')) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you know what the HTML will be each time? You could remove them all and then add one.

Comment: Can you put the HTML you'd want after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this with [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+`. Very easy and also the fastest solution, since the browser's CSS engine will be used to select elements:

```js
$(".column-hr + .column-hr").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column-hr">hr</div>
<div class="column-hr">hr</div>
<div class="column-dude">dude</div>
<div class="column-hr">hr</div>
<div class="column-hr">hr</div>
<div class="column-dude">dude</div>
<div class="column-hr">hr</div>
```

How it works: CSS selector `.column-hr + .column-hr` selects `.column-hr` elements that have immediate previous sibling `.column-hr`. As the result this expression will select *all* adjacent `.column-hr` elements *except* the very first one, because the first one doesn't have another `.column-hr` right before it.

Comment: Yes, of course. All jQuery versions support `+` selector.

Comment: The difference with my answer (besides using the sibling selector) is that the first column-hr will be the one that remains, while mine will preserve the last one. +1, never seen the sibling selector before.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$( ".column-hr" ).each(function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
    console.log($(this).next().attr('class'));

    if ($(this).next().attr('class') == 'column-hr') {
        $(this).remove();
    }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aodnw5ns/

Answer (score 0):

```
var classesToRemove = ['column-hr', 'column-dude'];
var $elements;

for (var i = 0, l = classesToRemove.length; i < l; i++) {
  // Find elements
  $elements = $('.' + classesToRemove[i]);

  var elementsLength = $elements.length;

  // If there is more than one element
  if (elementsLength > 1) {
    // get all elements except the first
    $elements = $elements.slice(1, elementsLength);
    // remove them
    $elements.remove();
  }
}

// prevent memory leaks
$elements = null;
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drbgbxaa/)**